# I need help in solving this trigonometry related quartic equation.

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, quartics

I'm doing this calculation whereby I determine where the light source would be reflected on the sphere to the eye relative to its position. Assuming light travels in a straight line and the ray is perpendicular to the eye, I would like to find where it would reflect to the eye on the surface normal of the sphere.

[Plan view of the sphere diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ZT2.jpg)

The radius of the sphere is $1$, the $x$-distance from the eye to the center of the sphere is $\frac{1}{\sin15}$ and $y$-distance is $1$. With that, I identified the triangle where I can calculate the angle of incidence using sine rule. With the light ray being perpendicular to the eye, I established that $2i+b=90$, therefore $b=90-2i$ which we would be substituting in our equation to find angle i.
$$\frac{\sin(180-i)}{H}=\frac{\sin(a-b)}{1}$$
$$\frac{\sin(i)}{H}=\sin(a-(90-2i))=-\cos(a+2i)$$
$$\frac{\sin(i)}{H}=\sin(a)\sin(2i)-\cos(a)\cos(2i)$$
$$\sin(i)=\sin(2i)-\frac{\cos(2i)}{\sin15}$$

Here I was able to use guess and check to get the answer but I want to learn how to solve it by calculation so that I may be able to calculate other distances. I would also like to point out that $H\sin(a)=1$ and $H\cos(a)=\frac{1}{\sin15}$ based on the diagram.

$$\sin(i)=2\sin(i)\cos(i)-\frac{2\cos^2(i)-1}{\sin15}$$
$$2\sin(i)\cos(i)-\sin(i)=\frac{2\cos^2(i)-1}{\sin15}$$
$$\sin(i)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(i)}=\frac{2\cos^2(i)-1}{\sin15(2\cos(i)-1)}$$
$$1-\cos^2(i)=\frac{(2\cos^2(i)-1)^2}{\sin^215(2\cos(i)-1)^2}$$
$$\sin^215(1-\cos^2(i))(2\cos(i)-1)^2-(2\cos^2(i)-1)^2=0$$
I'm currently stuck here as I realised I couldn't factor this equation and have no idea how to solve this from this point onward. I am still trying to understand polynomial equations and would appreciate some guidance on it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your last equation is correct and that everything is in degree, for simpler notations let $a=\sin ^2(15 {}^{\circ})$ and $c=\cos (i {}^{\circ})$.

Expanding, we have
$$4( a+1) c^4-4 a c^3-(3 a+4) c^2+4 a c+(1-a)=0$$ which is quartic that, if you want nightmares, you could solve with radicals.

We have $a=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}$. Plotting the function for $-1 \leq c \leq 1$, we see four roots. Zooming more and more around the roots, we see that they are close to $-0.83$, $-0.52$, $0.68$ and $0.74$.

To polish the roots, Newton method converges in a couple of iterations and the slutions are
$$c_1=-0.831525\qquad c_2=-0.523722\qquad c_3= 0.682282\qquad c_4=0.735747$$ No, do not forget that $c_k=\cos (i_k {}^{\circ})$ then $i_k {}^{\circ}$.